# Sum columns from multiples DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas

I have N Dataframes, named data1,data2...etc
Each dataframe has two columns 'X' and 'Y'. The lenght of each dataframe it's not the same.
I need a new dataframe consisting in the sum of the 'X' columns.
I just tried something like:

```
dataframesum = pd.DataFrame(0, index=np.arange(Some_number),columns = ['X']
for i in range(N):
dataframesum.add(globals()['Data%s'%i]['X'], fill_values = 0)
```

but it doesn't works (i'm not sure what should be the value of Some_number) and i am getting the next error:

```
NotImplementedError: fill_value 0 not supported
```

Comment: Are you `N` DataFrames stored in a list, or a dictionary?

Comment: in a dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a dictionary to store an arbitrary number of variables.

So let's assume you have dataframes stored in `dfs = {1: df1, 2: df2, 3: df3...}`.

You can then concatenate them via [`pd.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.concat.html):

```
df_concat = pd.concat(list(dfs.values()))
```

Finally, you can sum columns via [`pd.DataFrame.sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html):

```
sums = df_concat.sum()
```

To take advantage of vectorised operations, you should avoid a manual `for` loop. In addition, use of `globals()` is poor practice, and can be avoided by using `dict` or `list` to store your dataframes.

Comment: i am using a dictionary. I tried what you say, but i need a dataframe consisting in the sum column to column of the X columns

Comment: `i need a dataframe consisting in the sum column`. Sorry, I don't understand this.